# Problem with httpContext.RewritePath on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, global-asax

I am using `HttpContext.RewritePath` in Global.asax for some URL rewriting, and it works very well in my development environment on the Cassini server. But when I copy it to the production server running IIS 7, it isn't working. I have also tried to use `Context.Server.TransferRequest` but then I get the error: "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode." on both Cassini *and* IIS 7 (on IIS 7 the website is running in "Integrated" mode in the AppPool).

I rewrite all URLs on the website like `/[The main menuname]/[pagename].aspx` e.g. from `/web/thesite.aspx?mainmenu=manager` to `/manager/thesite.aspx` OR `/web/theOtherSite.aspx?mainmenu=about` to `/about/theOtherSite.aspx`, and so on...

Comment: Why not use IIS for development if you're on Vista or Window 7. Or you can use IIS 7 express http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx, that you you'll hopefully be able to debug your problem. Also, can you reformat the urls better so we can make sense of "before" and "after" urls?

Comment: Try using [Tracing of failed Requests](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/) to see what's happening "behind the scenes".

Comment: It looks like IIS 7 is not supporting RewritePath :-( So I have to user TransferRequest, but i isn't working

Comment: My URL is:
before: www.mydomain.com/Manager/mysite.aspx
After RewritwPath: www.mydomain.com/web/mysite.aspx?mainmenu=Manager

Comment: What does "it isn't working" mean?

Comment: Getting the error: "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."

Comment: IIS 7 doe support Re-write path obviously and I believe so does IIS 7 express. Yes you need to configure the app pool to use Integrated mode.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753449(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Now i have also tried setting the apppool too Clasic mode, stil same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that i need to add the following to web.config

```
 <configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
</system.webServer></configuration>
```